# Calculating distance between multiple points within buffer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, buffer, expression

[image]

I am very new to QGIS.

Attached is an image of my QGIS project so far. In this, you have the pinkish points of the "Point_centers" layer and green points labeled "Point_trees" which are tree species that I am interested in. What I want to do is calculate the distance of the Point_centers to all the Point_trees within the 15 meter buffer layer I created. I want it to calculate the distances regardless whether or not the Trees overlap in different buffers.

Answer (score 7):

To get the distance from the center point to each tree inside the buffer, use this expression:

```
array_foreach (
    overlay_nearest( 
        'Point_trees', 
        $geometry, 
        max_distance:=15, 
        limit:=-1
    ),
    length (
        make_line (
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    )
)
```

This generates an array of distances from the center to each tree inside the buffer. The get the sum of all distances, enclose the expression in an `array_sum()` function.

*The expression calculates the lengths of the black lines. These lines here are created based on the same expression for visualization purpose:*
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get a result similar to the one showed by Matt in his answer to this question and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461010) within the Geometry Generator, so that the changes in distances are visualized immediately without generating specific layers?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there's no easy way to create individual labels as Geometry Generator can have just one individual label per feature - but here, you want have several different labels per point (one for each connecting line).

Comment: And what about calculating the number of lines/connections existent for each point and store them as an attribute?

Comment: @HyPhens this is possible: replace `array_foreach` with `array_length` to calculate the number of lines for each point

Comment: I noticed that the result is always '+1', probably because it counts also the point with itself, so maybe a '-1' at the end of the expression can help.

Comment: Is it possible to put the sum of existent lines as a graduated value by expression _within_ the same layer, or a duplicate is always necessary?

Answer (score 5):

To calculate the distances in a table:

1. First ensure that your buffers layer and trees layer have a field with a unique identifier. I used `tree_id` and `buffer_id`.
2. Perform a spatial join between the trees and the buffers using a *one-to-many* join type. This will give you a new points layer where points are duplicated when they are within more than one buffer.

[image]

Tree `T23` now appears 3 times, in buffers `2`, `3`, and `4`.

[image]

3. Then use this expression in the Field Calculator on the joined layer:

```
length(
    make_line(
        $geometry,      
        centroid(geometry(get_feature(                  -- get the centroid of the buffer that matches the buffer_id of the joined point. 
                              layer:='buffers', 
                              attribute:='buffer_id',   -- 'buffer_id' in single quotes is the field name
                              value:="buffer_id")))     -- "buffer_id" in double quotes is the field value of the current joined point
                                                                             
        
    )
)
```

[image]

Now each tree point has a distance to its corresonding buffer centroid:

[image]

Example:

[image]

(The lines are for visualisation purposes only)

Comment: How did you get the last picture, with the lines labelled with the lengths?

Comment: The lines were created with a [Geometry Generator symbol layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392618/use-qgis-expressions-to-create-geometries-difference-between-geometry-generator). The expression to create the lines is the same as above but without the outer `length()` function. The label text was created using the whole expression above.

Comment: The expression works well to get the distances, but I can't get the lines with the Geometry Generator and labels and I don't understand what is wrong... I just copied the same expression used to obtain the distances and removed `lenght()`...nothing appears

Comment: A couple of things to check: Did you change the output geometry type of the symbol layer to `line`, and are your layer and field names consistent with those in the expression?

Comment: I would say yes because, as said, I just copied the expression without the first function. I tried to change the target layer and the fields but nothing happens as well. I can obtain Babel's solution, but yours is more useful for my needs. About the GG, I left the Simple Marker and added a GG > Line > Simple Line

Comment: I am away from my computer at the moment so I can't test it. I will take a look a little later and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, wait for your updates.

Comment: See this question that covers the steps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461010

Answer (score 4):

You can use a virtual layer to compute the distance and optionally draw a line to the center point.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. You can add any field from the point or polygon layer.

```sql
select make_line(pt.geometry, st_centroid(poly.geometry)) as geometry, 
       st_distance(pt.geometry, st_centroid(poly.geometry)) as dist
from myPolygonLayer poly
join myPointLayer pt
 on st_intersects(pt.geometry,poly.geometry)
```

[image]

PS: See how accurate is my buffer polygon?! That's why it is usually better NOT to select point within a buffer, but rather to select points within a distance of another point.