# Using QGIS Geometry Generator to create labels between associated features in different layers

Tags: qgis, labeling, layers, geometry-generator

This question arose from a comment on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/426233/128665) to [Calculating distance between multiple points within buffer using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/426206/115).

I have followed the steps there, which use a one-to-many spatial join to generate separate features for each point that is within a buffer polygon in another layer (called `buffers`). Points that fall within multiple buffers are duplicated. The result is a layer called `joined`. The points layer has a field called `buffer_id` containing the id of the joined buffer polygon.

The lines connecting the points with their associated buffer centroid can be visualised using a *Geometry Generator* symbol layer like so:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_within(
            'buffers',
            @geometry
        ),
        make_line(@geometry, centroid(@element))
    )
)
```

How can I create the labels for the lines as shown in the screenshot?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Although, the expression to get lines returns "Eval Error: Cannot convert to geometry". The expression is used on the `joined` layer with a Simple Marker and a Geometry Generator LinesString/MultiLineString.  I'm using QGIS 3.26.1.

Comment: It is hard to diagnose the problem without seeing your project setup. You have a layer called `buffers` that the `joined` points are within? Also - depending on your version of QGIS you might also need to use `$geometry` instead of `@geometry` (the `@` prefix for the `geometry` variable was implemented relatively recently).

Comment: Yes, I solved it using a newer version (3.28.7). Everything now works fine.

Comment: The very last question: with this solution it is not necessary to calculate distances among points with the Field Calculator, but I visualize also '0' distances (i.e. the distance of a point from its duplicate). Is it possible to change the expression for labelling in order to avoid '0' values (I tried but I obtained only '0' and '1')?

Comment: The question/solution here refers to calculating distances to features in another layer, not the same layer, so it is outside the scope of this post. However, you can use rule-based labelling to label only features with distance > 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Prerequisite

For this solution to work, the point layer must have a field (in this example called `buffer_id`) that contains the id of the joined buffer polygon. The solution was implemented in QGIS 3.30.3.

##### Label values

The values for the labels are generated with this expression:

```
to_int(                                           -- optional cast to integer
    length(
        make_line(
            $geometry,      
            centroid(
                geometry(
                    get_feature(                  -- get the centroid of the buffer that matches the buffer_id of the joined point. 
                        layer:='buffers', 
                        attribute:='id',   -- 'id' in single quotes is the `id` field name in the buffers layer
                        value:="buffer_id"        -- "buffer_id" in double quotes is the field value of the **current point** in the joined layer
                    )
                )
            )                                                                        
        )
    )
)
```

The expression finds the feature in the `buffers` layer where the buffer_id matches the joined field in the points layer, makes a line from the buffer centroid to the current point and gets the length of that line.

The expression is entered by clicking the [image: epsilon] button next to the *Value* text edit. The mode is changed to `Offset from point` and the lower center quadrant is selected.

[image]

##### Label placement

The labels are placed at the midpoint of the connecting lines using this expression:

```
centroid(                                 -- get the centroid (mid-point) of the line joining the point with the centroid of its associated buffer
    make_line(
        $geometry,      
        centroid(
            geometry(
                get_feature(                  
                    layer:='buffers', 
                    attribute:='id',      -- 'id' in single quotes is the `id` field name in the buffers layer
                    value:="buffer_id"
                )
            )
        )                                                                                
    )
)
```

The expression is entered by checking *Geometry Generator* and clicking on the <kbd>...</kbd> button next to the text edit area. `Point / MultiPoint` is chosen as the geometry type.

[image]

##### Label rotation

The labels are rotated parallel to the line using this expression:

```
main_angle(                              -- get the angle of the line joining the point with the centroid of its associated buffer
    make_line(
        $geometry,      
        centroid(
            geometry(
                get_feature(                  
                    layer:='buffers', 
                    attribute:='id',     -- 'id' in single quotes is the `id` field name in the buffers layer
                    value:="buffer_id"
                )
            )
        )                                                                                
    )
) + 90                                 -- add 90 to make the label text parallel to the line
```

The expression is entered as a *Data defined override* by clicking the [image] button next to *Rotation* in the `Data defined` section

[image]