# Calculating and visualizing interdistances among points in QGIS (Delauney Triangulation)

Tags: qgis, point, distance, points-to-line, delaunay

I have a point layer:

[image]

and I would like to calculate and visualize interdistances among the points with lines automatically to see if there is any trend.

The main issue is that if I connect all the points (using for instance solutions shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426206/calculating-distance-between-multiple-points-within-buffer-using-qgis/)) all the points are connected, getting unrealistic results for my purposes (each point represents a city).

What **I would like** to obtain (*green*) is something like this:

[image]

And what **I would not like** to obtain (*red*) is something like this:

[image]

I am not sure a completely automated method exists, maybe some manual edits will always be needed. And, of course, I am asking this because I would like to avoid using any buffer, i.e. setting an interdistance value before the analysis.

Comment: Your question is unclear. A point (in the image) has only one closest point. "Lines in the image" and "lines should connect the closest points" don't match.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, what I meant is that, for instance, the upper point on the left should not connect with the lower point on the right, and lines should not cross each others. I can edit the question accordingly.

Comment: The 2nd image is the final result you need?

Comment: Like the Delaunay triangulation : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#delaunay-triangulation ?

Comment: @HyPhens: can you edit your question and describe all the context and things you want. For example here, a delaunay triangulation seems to answers your need, but you specify in your last comment you want the interdistances. It's better to be the more precise at start, you'll have more chance to have a great answer.

Comment: @J.Monticolo, yes, I will rephrase the entire question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know if this will give you the results you want?

1. Delaunay triangulation to create polygons
2. Polygons to lines
3. Explode lines to split each line at the vertices
4. Drop duplicate geometries

[image]

If you get "unrealistic" long lines you can filter them with an expression. For example add an "Extract by expression" after Drop duplicate lines.

With your point data this expression will exclude your red lines. "Extract lines shorter than 1.7*mean line length":

```
 $length<= 
 1.7*aggregate( layer:='Cleaned', aggregate:='mean', 
 expression:=$length
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BERA for this another great answer. I think it answers almost the question, but it some cases, it will give some "unrealistic" distances like the red line at the right in te OP's post.

Comment: Bera and @J. Monticolo, is Delaunay Triangulation In QGIS unique for every dataset, or different outputs are possible? Because I think that in geometry some alternative results can be possible (and in my case it would change the distance values).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation : unique for a dataset.

Comment: Bera and @J.Monticolo, I still think that Delaunay Triangulation offers multiple possible solutions (for instance, think of an irregular rhombus), but it's probably the best solution available other than drawing manually every connection. If so, I will accept the answer.

Comment: I've executed the algorithm (the model) 1000 times each on two different point datasets and the result was the same on all iterations